# Ruby fb_graph app_request, or Request Dialog

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to do an app request, but my requests do not apear in the notification (the globe icon) and I don't know what to do more.

Just to confirm that i've done everything ok, I have followed the JS SDK Request Dialog example:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

At first time it seems to work ok, and I have a list of my request, but can't see none in facebook.

What I have done so far:

used the fb_graph gem ( https://github.com/nov/fb_graph )

```
u = FbGraph::User.me(User.find(2).fb_access_token)
u.app_request!(:message => 'punk message')
```

After that if I do u.app_requests, I can see a list of requests.

As this seems not to work I after tried the Facebook JS SDK, and the result is the same.

My Question is: What am I doing wrong, or missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more I'm around it, the more I'm favoring the Javascript SDK over server side code.  Is there a reason for your app to require to do anything serverside, or can you accomplish the same thing client side?  Can you give us an example of the Javascript code you tried that failed?

Comment: Hi, I figured out that I need to set the app to be a canvas app aswell. Although I think the same way (about this being done through client side).

Comment: I didn't accept the answer, I just agree, but still need a way to understand that is or that is not possible to send user notifications from user to user. If the Facebook JS SDK can do a user-to-user how can I do it server side? I think this Idea isn't clear enough to me, so if someone can explain it to me, it will be a relief to explain to the bosses.